# Node.js and modules on a system where I can't sudo

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower

I would like to use node on a system on which I don't have sudo permissions.

I downloaded node and followed a guide on how to install npm packages globally without sudo permissions.

Node and npm commands works well. My problem is that installed packages (in my case bower and gulp), search for node in `/usr/bin/env: node:`
So if I run bower I get `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

I can't create a ln in that directory because I don't have permission. How can I tell bower and gulp to search for node in another path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that installed packages (in my case bower and gulp), search for node in `/usr/bin/env: node:`

They most certainly do not. Here is the first line in `gulp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

It is the same in `bower`. Note that it does not have any of the two colons that you show.

Your question also suggest you are misinterpreting the error message. **There is nothing there that implies you should have `sudo` capabilities.** That message tells you that `env` is unable to find `node`. Let me illustrate with a name that does not exist on my system:

```
$ /usr/bin/env nonexistent
/usr/bin/env: nonexistent: No such file or directory
$ env nonexistent
env: nonexistent: No such file or directory
```

If I do `env node` it will start node. The error you are getting is exactly in the form of the error messages above: you get the path used to launch `env`, which is the full path if that's what was used, the name of the command that was not found and the description of the problem.

Why does it fail? **It fails because `env` is not able to find `node` among the paths specified in your `PATH` environment variable.**

I don't know what your guide told you but if you install locally, you either have to install in such a way that the binaries of Node will be in a path already covered by your `PATH`, or you should modify the file that sets your environment variables to add the paths in which `node` and `npm` were installed. For `bash`, you'd modify `~./profile` like this:

```
PATH=/path/to/the/node/binaries:$PATH
```

I prepend to make sure that the path you want will take precedence over anything that could also be installed in the system locations (`/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to edit the bowserrc file?

> Bower can be configured using JSON in a .bowerrc file. For example:

```
{
  "directory": "app/components/",
  "analytics": false,
  "timeout": 120000,
  "registry": {
    "search": [
      "http://localhost:8000",
      "https://bower.herokuapp.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

> The config is obtained by merging multiple configurations by this order of importance:

- CLI arguments via --config
- Environment variables
- CLI arguments via --config
- Environment variables
- Local .bowerrc located in the current working directory
- All .bowerrc files upwards the directory tree
- .bowerrc file located in user’s home folder (~)
- .bowerrc file located in the global folder (/)

Found in:
http://bower.io/docs/config/

Comment: Can't find any .bowerrc , but I can create one my user home folder or modify the .bashrc